# Nova linha na tabela a cada 3 colunas

Tags: php, html, mysql, tabela-html

Eu tenho uma tabela que tem que ter 3 colunas por linha. Os dados das 3 colunas eu pego do banco. O meu problema é que quando exibir 3 colunas, quero que os próximos resultados apareça na linhas de baixo, ou seja, exibir de 3 em 3, só que não estou conseguindo, pois o código que fiz ele exibe 2 e na linha de baixo 1 e assim por diante.

```
<table border="0" width="650">
<?php
$i = 1;
while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($SQLContentCalendario)){
echo ($i % 3) ? '' : '<tr>';
echo '<td valign="top" width="200">';
...
echo '</td>';
echo ($i % 3) ? '' : '</tr>';
$i++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<table border="0" width="650">
<?php
    $i = 1;
    echo '<tr>';    
    while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($SQLContentCalendario)){
            echo '<td valign="top" width="200">';
            ...
            echo '</td>';
        if(($i % 3) == 0){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu!