# Imprimindo valores com foreach em três <td> diferentes em html

Tags: php, html

Bom, pessoal. Quero listar os dados do meu banco em uma tabela HTML, mas isso em três colunas `<td>`, quando estourasse esse valor, ele criaria mais uma linha `<tr>`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
                    foreach($produtos as $produto):
                ?>
                <td>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="produtos/imagens/<?=$produto['imagem']?>" class="imagem_item">
                        <div class="espaco_nome">
                            <span class="titulo_item"><?=$produto['nome']?></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="preco_item">R$ <?=$produto['preco']?></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <?php
                    endforeach;
                ?>
```

Nesse caso, ele imprimiria tudo na mesma linha da tabela. Como faço para ele criar três colunas e depois criar mais uma linha?

Comment: Relacionado : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61347/nova-linha-na-tabela-a-cada-3-colunas/61348

Comment: concordo @GuilhermeLautert porém já deixei uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só usar a lógica :)

```
<?php
                $i = 1;
                foreach($produtos as $produto):
                  if($i == 1) {
                     echo "<tr>";
                  }
                ?>
                <td>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="produtos/imagens/<?=$produto['imagem']?>" class="imagem_item">
                        <div class="espaco_nome">
                            <span class="titulo_item"><?=$produto['nome']?></span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="preco_item">R$ <?=$produto['preco']?></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <?php
                    if($i == 3)
                        echo "</tr>";
                        $i = 1;
                    } else {
                        $i++;
                    }
                    endforeach;
                    if ($i != 1) { echo "</tr>"; }
                ?>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso Hiago ;) Obrigado por sua resposta ;)

Comment: Disponha, assim que possível marque como correta a resposta.